# Можно ли запустить .exe через windows установленную через qemu, но что бы графика рендерилась через хост-машину?

Tags: linux, windows, exe, qemu

Можно ли запустить .exe через windows установленную через qemu, но что бы графика рендерилась через хост-машину?

Comment: ОС хоста на которой установлен qemu? Что за .exe приложение и где развернуто?

Comment: рендерить на хосте нельзя, но вот пробросить внутрь видновой машины с линукса видеокарту(и поставить на нее драйвера) - тогда будет работать почти также быстро. есть много гайдов. например этот https://blog.zerosector.io/2018/07/28/kvm-qemu-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/